# Shifting 2D array in Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog, bit-shift

What is the proper way to shift a 2D array n arbitrary bits? If that is possible at all. Say I have

```
module foo(input        clk,
           input [31:0] shift_amount);
.
.
.
reg [31:0] array[0:79];
.
.
.
always@(posedge clk) begin
   if(!reset)
      // so something
   else
      // shift my array by the shift amount
end
endmodule
```

For 1D array, I can do something like array << shift_amount

but say I have an array like this

```
 0: XXXXXXXX 
 1: XXXXXXXX
 2: XXXXXXXX
 3: c0ffeeee
 4: c0dec0de
 .
 .
79: 1234568A
```

I want to shift everything up by n position (3 for this example), like

```
 0: c0ffeeee
 1: c0dec0de
 2: 13e1441a
 3: 12441111
 4: fffff22a
 .
 .
 . 
77: 00000000
78: 00000000
79: 00000000
```

Can it be done? If so how?

Answer (score 3):

Use a for-loop. Remember to use an index guard and use non-blocking assignment (`<=`).

```
//...
integer i;
always@(posedge clk) begin
   if (!reset) begin
      // so something
   end
   else begin
      // shift my array by the shift amount
      for (i=0; i<80; i=i+1)
         if (i+shift_amount < 80) // index guard
            array[i] <= array[i+shift_amount];
         else
            array[i] <= 32'b0;
   end
end
//...
```

Comment: Correct. If the synthesizer is smart it may give a smaller mux for the larger indexes. For example index 79 has two possible inputs, index 77 has four possible inputs. Index 0 is the worse case, 81-to-1 mux (itself + 79 other entries + 32'b0). There could be a timing problem with such a large mux. If so, you will need to pipeline which will use additional clocks.